# How to "rename" attribute names in a knockout arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have this knockout array:

```
self.persons = ko.observableArray([
    { "PersonId" : "0", "PName" : "Miss" },
    { "PersonId Id" : "1", "PName" : "Postman Pat" }
]);
```

Is there an elegant(easy way to map the attributes "PersonId" and "PName" to, say, "id" and "name" ?

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a new objects with required props:

And then, fill persons array with ItemViewModel objects:

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    var items = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
        return {
            id: item.PersonId,
            name: item.PName
        };
    });
    self.persons = ko.observableArray(items);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `ko.utils.arrayMap` here; `arrayForEach` will simply discard the return values.